# How to use bootstrap with Eclipse - content Assist?

Tags: eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, content-assist

I'm using Eclipse MARS 4.5.0.

I searched Eclipse-market plug-in to support bootStrap content-assist
and StakcOverFlow but I can't find proper thing.

when I type

`<div class=`

and press ctrl+space I want to see container or container-fluid

or

`<a class=`

then I want to see btn or btn-lg

Is it possible?

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but you might need to type `"` and then ctrl+space, since HTML attribute values have to be in quotes. e.g. `<div class="`

Comment: I have got a message that "No repository found".

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse.
Help-> Eclipse Marketplace.
In Search box type **Enide-Eclipse bootstrap e4 0.14**. Just Install it.

Comment: This is perfect! it should be accepted as the answer. I dont know why it is not yet.

Comment: I installed and what's next? Should I set something?

Comment: See the things are yet in a beta version of development. So the things currently in development. So you will be getting the suggestions for common css only not for the bootstrap.@Dr.Midori

Comment: I installed it and nothing is changed ;-(